# Task delegation in Python/Redis

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, design-patterns, redis

I have an issue thinking of an architecture that'll solve the following problem:

I have a web application (producer) that receives some data on request. I also have a number of processes (consumers) that should process this data. 1 request generates 1 batch of data and should be processes by only 1 consumer.

My current solution consists of receiving the data, cache-ing it in memory with Redis, sending a message through a message channel that data has been written while the consumers are listening on the same channel, and then the data is processed by the consumers. The issue here is that **I need to stop multiple consumers from working on the same data**. So how can I inform the other consumers that I have started working on this task?

Producer code (flask endpoint):

```
    data = request.get_json()
    db = redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool)
    db.set(data["externalId"], data)
    # Subscribe to the batches channel and publish the id
    db.pubsub()
    db.publish('batches', request_key)
    results = None
    result_key = str(data["externalId"])

    # Wait till the batch is processed
    while results is None:
        results = db.get(result_key)
        if results is not None:
            results = results.decode('utf8')

    db.delete(data["externalId"])
    db.delete(result_key)
```

Consumer:

```
    db = redis.Redis(connection_pool = pool)
    channel = db.pubsub()
    channel.subscribe('batches')

    while True:
        try:
            message = channel.get_message()
            message_data = bytes(message['data']).decode('utf8')
            external_id = message_data.split('-')[-1]
            data = json.loads(db.get(external_id).decode('utf8'))
            result = DataProcessor.process(data)
            db.set(str(external_id), result)
        except Exception:
            pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PUBSUB is often problematic for task queuing for exactly this reason. From the docs (https://redis.io/topics/pubsub):

> SUBSCRIBE, UNSUBSCRIBE and PUBLISH implement the Publish/Subscribe messaging paradigm where (citing Wikipedia) senders (publishers) are not programmed to send their messages to specific receivers (subscribers). Rather, published messages are characterized into channels, without knowledge of what (if any) subscribers there may be.

A popular alternative to consider would be to implement "publish" by pushing an element to the end of a Redis list, and "subscribe" by having your worker poll that list at some interval (exponential backoff is often an appropriate choice). In order to avoid cases where multiple workers get the same job, use `lpop` to get and remove an element from the list. Redis is single-threaded, so you're guaranteed only one worker will receive each element.

So, on the publish side, aim for something like this:

```
db = redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool)
db.rpush("my_queue", task_payload)
```

And on the subscribe side, you can safely run a loop like this in parallel as many times as you need:

```
while True:
    db = redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool)
    payload = db.lpop("my_queue")
    if not payload:
        continue
    < deserialize and process payload here >
```

Note this is a last-in-first-out queue (LIFO) since we're pushing onto the right side with `rpush` and popping off the left with `lpop`. You can implement the FIFO version trivially by combining `lpush`/`lpop`.